# How to draw dot inside shape turtle python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am new with Turtle python library and I am trying to draw turtle dot inside the shape (square), which should look like on the picture below. The problem is that when I am trying to do this the shape covers the dot and I see only the shape (square).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRFaY.png)

My code:

```
def add_dot_square():
    obj = Turtle()
    obj.penup()
    obj.shape("square")
    obj.shapesize(1.5, 1.5)
    obj.color("orange")
    obj.goto(0, 0)
    obj.dot(20, "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

Turtle's can't appear behind things they draw, only other turtles (and even that's tricky.)  Instead of the turtle *being* the square, have the turtle *draw* or *stamp* the square, and then place the dot atop it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def add_dot_square(obj):
    obj.penup()
    obj.shape('square')
    obj.shapesize(1.5)
    obj.color('orange')
    obj.goto(0, 0)

    obj.stamp()
    obj.dot(20, 'red')

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

add_dot_square(turtle)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

> I still ha[v]e a problem when I want to for example move this
> square and dot

Let's rearrange the code a bit and add some motion:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def add_dot_square(obj):
    obj.clear()
    obj.stamp()
    obj.dot(20, 'red')

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(1.5)
turtle.color('orange')
turtle.penup()

for _ in range(360):
    turtle.circle(100, extent=1)
    add_dot_square(turtle)
    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: @Patycka, I've added some additional code to demonstrate animation.